# Render Highcharts inside DIV with dynamically generated ID in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have an AngularJS directive that creates `div` modules with dynamic `id` defined in the attributes.

Example:

`<my-directive containerId="myId"></my-directive>`

and then in the definition of the directive's template I have:

`<div id="{{ containerId }}"></div>`

Eventually I'd like to render a Highcharts chart inside this `div` with the dynamic `id`, however Highcharts doesn't seem to be able to find the `div`. I've also tried to use `ng-attr-id` but wih no better results.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you loading Highcharts? There are some AngularJS directives/wrapper for Highcharts, but nothing official for AngularJS (only for Angular 2+, so Angular). If Highcharts not able to find the div, then it probably doesn't exists at the time you are trying to build a chart, so it's a race problem. Try loading Highcharts chart later in the app life cycle or in a callback of your dynamic-id-adder if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not-so-optimal solution. Race condition still exists.
But it should work most of the time.

Pesudo code

```
controller
  init logics
  draw a placeholder chart
  AJAX to data
    on success
      INIT highcharts
    on failure
      handle failure
```